# Basic python string

Tags: python, string

We just started working with string in my CSCI class, but I'm confused with a recent assignment.

> You are given a long string:

```
"""Justin$Calculus$90$Java$85$Python88$
Taylor$Calculus$73$Java$95$Python86$
Drew$Calculus$80$Java$75$Python94$
"""
```

> The string has three lines. It contains three students’ scores of
>   three courses. Write a function `findScore(student, subject)`. When
>   you call the function such as `findScore(‘Drew’,’Java’)`, the function
>   prints `“Drew got 75 of the course Java.”`
>
> In addition to the function `findScore(student, subject)`, you can
>   write other functions. All the functions are inside one program.

I would assume that I need to assign this string to a variable, but do I use one variable, or one for each line?

Any ideas of a start would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to python so bear with me. Also, what is the significance of the `$` signs?

Comment: `$` has no special meaning in Python strings, it's just an arbitrary separator used in this string.

Comment: what have you come up so far?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no `$` between `Python` and the corresponding score?

Comment: It looks like the `$` are delimiters to separate each field. It looks like the string should probably have additional `$`s after each `Python`, otherwise this assignment becomes harder than it was probably meant to be.

Comment: What I want to know is why are `Drew`, `Taylor` and `Justin` taking a `Java` course if they're already learning `Python`?  :-X

Comment: @mgilson In order to know the enemy, probably. And in order to know how it is not done, resp. how to do it in a complicated way... (SCNR)

Comment: @glglgl -- Yes, that must be it.  I can't see any other reason ... :-)

Answer (score 6):

have a look at [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).  You can use it to split a string up into a list:

```
"foo bar baz".split()     #['foo','bar','baz'] (split on any whitespace)
"foo$bar$baz".split('$')  #['foo','bar','baz']
```

From here, it's just a matter of splitting the string into the appropriate lists, and then iterating over the lists properly to pick out the elements that you need.

Additionally, you could use [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to get the index of the class name and split your string there using slicing *before* splitting on `$`.  That would make it easier to get the particular score (without an additional iteration):

```
s = 'foo$bar$baz'
s_new = s[s.find('bar'):]  #'bar$baz'
baz = s_new.split('$')[1]
print baz
```

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way to read this would be to use the `csv` module. It's intended for Comma Separated Values, but you can change the delimiter and use `$` instead.

You would need to use `delimiter='$'` as an argument to your `reader`.

Comment: They _started working with string_, Bruno!

Comment: @SilentGhost, yes, you're right. I suppose it could be useful later.

Answer (score 0):

store string in a variable, say:

```
strs="""Justin$Calculus$90$Java$85$Python88$
Taylor$Calculus$73$Java$95$Python86$
Drew$Calculus$80$Java$75$Python94$
"""
```

loop over `strs.split()` using a for loop , i.e  `for line in strs.split()`
(using `strs.split()` will return a list containing all lines, splitted at whitespace)

now for each line use `line.rstrip("$").split('$')`, it'll return something like this for the first line:

```
['Justin', 'Calculus', '90', 'Java', '85', 'Python88']
```

`rstrip("$")` will remove the rightmost `$` from the line